# Same activity only once in stack

Tags: android

I can't get the following to work.

**Activities:** A (Launcher Activity), B (Picture Activity), C (UserProfile Activity)

User behavior: A -> B1 -> C -> B2 (B1/B2 are the same activity, but different pictures.)

What I want to happen when pressing the back button: B2 -> C -> A

With which FLAG do I have to start Activity B? What I tried so far and what got me the wrong result

- **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**: B2 -> App gets closed
- **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**: B2 -> C -> B1 -> A
- **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**: B2 -> A
- **FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT**: This FLAG does start B1 instead of B2, because Activity B is already in the stack. It looks promising, because when going back its B1 -> C -> A. Do I have to combine this FLAG with another? I don't want to reorder B1 to the top of the stack, but remove it and start B2.

The UserProfile Activity gets started without any flags. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting the launch mode of the `B` activity to `singleInstance`

Comment: I tried all of the `launchMode` options. None of them worked as I wanted it to

Comment: What you can try is to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, pass some data in a `Bundle` to the activity `B` and update the activity according to the data passed.

Comment: Why not use activity B-> fragment C->activity B logic?

Comment: @B.Naeem Yes, see the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` as you said looks promising. It starts the same activity again but moves it in the history stack.

At first, this will restore the original state (picture B1), but you do receive the new Intent in Activity B. Use this to update the data:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent) {
    super.onNewIntent(newIntent)
    // update picture here from new newIntent
}
```

There are alternatives, such as setting `singleInstance` as launchmode in the manifest. But they all boil down to using `onNewIntent` to update the contents.